# Is it possible to fake acount information on a Dev machine?

Tags: 2007, development, email, error

I have a virtualized dev machine that is disconnected from the network. I want to add a local user (from the vm) to an attendee list. Can't do it because this user.. being local... does not have an email address. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just tested this by adding a local user account on my WFE.  As long as your WFE isn't a domain controller you can add a local account by doing this:

WFEName\LocalUserAccount

That authenticates for me and there isn't an email for this user...

Comment: As you can see from the above screen shot, this does not work for me.

Answer (score 0):

Can't you do this in Central Administration?
In the SSP you can edit personal information of a user, I think the e-mail address also. It's visible in the My Site settings.

PS: I can't see the screenshot, perhaps because I'm not logged in on Google Docs?

Answer (score 0):

If you're on a standalone box you can always create a windows account for the dummy user, then add them to the site as Matt said (WFEName\LocalUserAccount). That should be pretty straight forward; you can add as many dummy users as you need. You must create a windows account for the user before you can add them with this method though.

Not sure if it's just me, but I can't see your screenshot.